# my php code crashed wordpress staging site, not sure why

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Basically my code is supposed to take the data entry from a simple contact us form and send it to an external mysql database.

I was basing it off of https://www.billerickson.net/contact-form-integration/. When I was testing it on wordpress using the custom function plugin, the site just crashed on me giving http error 5000.

First time doing anything with wordpress/php so any pointers would be really helpful and appreciated.

```
<?php



global $wpdb

function be_db_connector( $fields, $entry, $form_data, $entry_id ) {

$username = example

$password = example
$database = example
$localhost = example
$wpdb = new wpdb('username','password','database','localhost');

$wpdb->insert('ProspectsDevOnly', array(
    'ProspectID' => Null,
    'InstitutionName' => Null,
    'Salution' => Null,
    'FirstName' => $fields['0']['value'],
    'LastName' => Null,
    'ProfessionalTitle' => Null,
    'InstitutionalTitle' => Null,
    'Phone' => $fields['2']['value'],
    'Email' => $fields['1']['value'],
    'DateCreated' => Null,
    'StatusFlag' => Null,
    )
    array(
            '%d',
            '%s',
            '%s',
            '%s',
            '%s',
            '%s',
            '%s',
            '%d',
            '%s',
            '%s',
            '%s',
    ) );


}
add_action( 'wpforms_process_complete_5917', 'be_crm_connector', 10, 4 );
```

Comment: Turn on error reporting to find out what the problem is i.e. error_reporting(E_ALL);

Also, there's a couple of very noticeable errors such as no semicolons in the first 3 lines and no comma separating the 2 arrays passed to insert()

Answer (score 0):

Your insert statement is incorrect. Your formats and the data that you want to insert don't match. One of the errors is that your phone number is being formatted as a %d when it should be %s. (There may be other errors, but that was the one that popped up when I looked at it)

Comment: Ok, ignoring the code bit - any idea where would I put this code? Currently testing stuff on a wp site hosted locally, but im not sure which file/folder I need to put this in